# Extract timestamp not defined using Leaflet Time Slider?

Tags: leaflet, timeslider

I am new to coding, so there may be many things wrong with my code. 
I am trying to build a Leaflet time slider for some point data. The geojson data is of sites where water was sampled for mercury levels and represents samples taken at different locations every five years. 
I want the data for each sample year to show at the same time.

So far I get points on the map, a slider that doesn't work, and an error: 
SliderControl.js:183 Uncaught ReferenceError: _extractTimeStamp is not defined
how do I define the extract timestamp?

Here is a sample of the data:

```
     {"type": "FeatureCollection",{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", 
    "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
    { "type": "Feature", 
    "properties": 
        { "Site ID": "JB002", 
        "Year": 1993, 
        "Hg": 0.050000, 
        "Place": "Jamaica Bay", 
        "Start": 1993, 
        "End": 1993 
        }, 
"geometry": { 
    "type": "Point", 
    "coordinates": [ -73.797836, 40.63616 ] } },
```

and the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var map = L.map('map').setView([40.748297,-73.941422], 11);
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/eichners/cjqvwjoam3d7p2smt18p3nssn/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZWljaG5lcnMiLCJhIjoiY2lrZzVneDI4MDAyZ3VkbTZmYWlyejUzayJ9.vEGckM-D3AjV4jXmdibXyw', 
{
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    attribution: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/">Mapbox</a> © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

var hgGeoJSON;
var sliderControl = null 
var hg

// 1. ADD Hg DATA
addHg(); 
function addHg() {
    $.getJSON( "geojson/Hg.geojson", function( data ) {
    var hg = data;   
            sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
                position: "topright",
                timeAttribute: "Year",
                time: '1000'
            });

    // POINT MARKER STYLE 
    var hgStyle=function (feature, latlng) {    
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, { 
                radius: (feature.properties.Hg)*2,
                 fillColor: '#FF0000',
                 color: '#FF0000',
                 weight: 1, 
                 fillOpacity: 0.6 
                })
            }       
    hgGeoJSON = L.geoJson(hg, {
    pointToLayer:  hgStyle, 
    //onEachFeature: hgClick    
    });

    //LOAD DATA LAYERS AT END TO CONTROL ORDER
    hgGeoJSON.addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(hgGeoJSON.getBounds()); 

    map.addControl(sliderControl);
    console.log("slider added");
```

//SliderControl.js:183 Uncaught ReferenceError: _extractTimeStamp is not defined
        sliderControl.startSlider();
      })
    };
    });

and, my html with scripts, etc.

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Leaflet time series _HEP Mercury</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <!--stylesheets-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href=jquery/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href=css/leaflet.css>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href=css/style.css>

            <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
            <script src="js/SliderControl.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class ="wrapper">
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="overlayContent">
            <!--<div id="info">-->
              <h1>Mercury 1993-2013</h1></br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What is missing is `layer` option in slider control definition:

```
sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
    layer: hgGeoJSON,
    position: "topright",
    timeAttribute: "Year",
    time: '1000'
});
```

Comment: Thank you TomazicM. That might make a difference, but I'm still getting an error re. extract Timestamp so I can't tell; SliderControl.js:183 Uncaught ReferenceError: _extractTimeStamp is not defined

Comment: And, I still get the error about layers: Error: You have to specify a layer via new SliderControl({layer: your_layer});
I'm not sure where else to specify it -- I did add to the slider options as suggested.

Comment: Move slider control definition out of `$.getJSON` call and put it just before `map.addControl(sliderControl)` statement.

Answer (score 0):

the `S` in "`extractTimestamp`" needs to be lowercase

Comment: that is correct in fact! there is a typo in `LeafletSlider
/SliderControl.js` source on line 183: `$('#slider-timestamp').html(_extractTimeStamp(...` -> should be changed here to `_extractTimestamp`